# Java no suitable method error:Sort three numbers

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am asked to write a test program, using a method that prompts the user to enter three numbers and invokes a method to display them in increasing order. With  the  book  am using to  autodidact and  learn  java,  I have  not  reached   the  use of   array or  other approaches that users  may  consider  appropriate  for the  question.  However , I  keep  getting temp  variable  may  not have  been  initialized and  used  error. I would appreciate guidance on  what’s wrong with the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Sort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create  Scanner
        Scanner s =new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter 3 Different numbers");
        int numb1 = s.nextInt();
        int numb2 =s.nextInt();
        int numb3 =s.nextInt();
        sort(numb1,numb2,numb3);
    }
    public  static void  sort(int x,int y, int z){
        int temp =0;
        if (y>z)
            temp =  y;
        y   = z;
        z    = temp;  
        if (x>y)
            temp  =  x;
        x    =  y;
        y    =  temp;
        if  (x>z)
            temp = x;
        x=   z ;
        z= temp;    

    System.out.println(x,y,z);
  }
}
```

Comment: just do: int temp = 0;

Comment: If `y` is not larger than `z`, then which value should `z` get through `temp`? Since `temp` has no value, what should happen? Btw: your code looks very much like you really want to use braces for your `if` blocks.

Comment: System.out.println(x,y,z); within method sort

Comment: @Tom. Am  getting  no  suitable  error  now.

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. putting it within  the  method  sort  give  no  suitable  method  error

Comment: @pumpin26 System.out.println(x + ", " + y + ", " + z);

Comment: @pumpin26 Now you'll have a logic error, but it is easy to fix

Comment: @pumpin26 you must add the {} if

Answer (score 0):

Use `int temp = 0;` As you conditions are not exhaustive, i.e. you do not consider all cases. What if x < y < z ?

Answer (score 0):

exaplain in code:

```
public static void sort(int x, int y, int z) {
    int temp = 0;
    //the smallest in x
    if (x > y) {
        temp = x;
        x = y;
        y = temp;
    }
    if (x > z) {
        temp = x;
        x = z;
        z = temp;
    }

    //the second smallest in y
    if (y > z) {
        temp = y;
        y = z;
        z = temp;
    }

    System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + z);
}
```

this algorithm using only variables is similar to bubble sort algorithm